# SQL error with "new query()" in ColdFusion / Railo script

Tags: mysql, sql, railo, cfml

I get a very unhelpful SQL error from Railo when trying to do an insert. I think it has something to do with the :param values I am passing to it; as when I take these out and replace them with a simple string, it works.

Here's my code (which sits inside a CFC):

```
local.registerUserQuery = new query();
            local.registerUserQuery.setDatasource("popwave");
            local.registerUserQuery.setSQL("

                INSERT INTO users (

                    userUUID,
                    userName,
                    userPassword,
                    userEmail,
                    userToken,
                    userCreated,
                    userBiography,
                    userCommentPoints,
                    userLinkPoints,
                    userImageID,
                    userRemoved,
                    userCategoriesOwner,
                    userCategoriesSubscribed

                )

                VALUES (

                    '#createUUID()#' , 
                    :userName , 
                    :userPassword , 
                    :userEmail , 
                    '#local.token#' , 
                    #createODBCDate(now())# , 
                    '' , 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    0 

                )

            "); 

            local.registerUserQuery.setName("registerUser");

            local.registerUserQuery.addParam( name="userName", value="#arguments.userName#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" ); 
            local.registerUserQuery.addParam( name="userPassword", value="#arguments.userPassword#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" ); 
            local.registerUserQuery.addParam( name="userEmail", value="#arguments.userEmail#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" );

            local.registerUserQuery.execute();
```

I cannot understand for the life of me why this is throwing an error! I need to be able to use :param's.

Here's the Railo error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 49
```

Examining that line number does not seem to point to anything related. This query is on something like line 200! And, as mentioned earlier...the SQL seems to work when I replace these :param values.

Is there actually something I am doing wrong here? Pulling my hair out!

Thanks,
Michael.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention, the Railo version is:

```
Railo 3.3.1.000 Error (database)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are experiencing issue [RAILO-1281](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-1281?_sscc=t) which should be fixed in 3.3.1.005.

> "RAILO-1281: When doing a query INSERT with CFScript "new query()" and using a
>   cfqueryparam with addParam(), the end ")" is removed"

As an aside, you should use `addParam` for all of the dynamic values.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've reverted to using a tag-based CFC now. I have tried using cfscript but I find it's just not that up to it yet. Oh well! Thanks for the info.

Comment: Btw, aside from upgrading the comments mention a fix you can manually apply to your `query.cfc` file pretty easily. But it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
local.registerUserQuery.setSQL(reReplace("

            INSERT INTO users (

                userUUID,
                userName,
                userPassword,
                userEmail,
                userToken,
                userCreated,
                userBiography,
                userCommentPoints,
                userLinkPoints,
                userImageID,
                userRemoved,
                userCategoriesOwner,
                userCategoriesSubscribed

            )

            VALUES (

                '#createUUID()#' , 
                :userName , 
                :userPassword , 
                :userEmail , 
                '#local.token#' , 
                #createODBCDate(now())# , 
                '' , 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0, 
                0 

            )

        ", "\t|\n", " ", "all"));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve anything, but instead creates another error:  parameter 2 of the function right must be a positive number now [0]. I've tried manually removing the spacing too; no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but it's a good idea to use addParam for all your variables, not just the sql Injection risks.

It ensures they are passed correctly with the correct formatting and also enforces a good habit. Maybe I'm wrong about this, but doesn't `#createODBCDateTime#` need to be inside single quotes for mySql? addParam will do this stuff for you.

Comment: I don't think it causes a problem, as the query worked when I simply removed all :param values. The date goes into a date/time column type, so it's not a varchar and thus exempt from the need to have quotes around it I think.

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551940/mysql-insert-datetime-into-other-datetime-field syntax error caused by NOT using single quotes. Also, see the official documentation. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html  And another reference to requiring the single quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452124/inserting-integer-and-datetime-from-php-to-mysql-5-0-db-error

Comment: @Jonathan - That pertains to date *strings*. `createODBCDate` returns a datetime *object* which is handled differently. Datetime objects do not need to be single quoted (in fact adding them causes a syntax error).

Comment: @Leigh OHhh, I forgot that returned an object. My CF is rusty.